# How to create switchable multi-language pdf form?

Tags: pdf

I want to create a pdf form for two language (Chinese/English) UI, and there's a button(s) or somethings on the form for language switch, is there anyway can make it? and how to do?
thanks!

Thanks for all reply!
Actually I got a sample like this,
[PDF Sample](https://www.asia.citibank.com/CBKWebPortal/ShowBinary/BEA%20Repository/Attachment/tw/tc/co/A_%E6%96%B0%E5%BC%8F%E5%A4%96%E5%B9%A3%E5%8C%AF%E5%87%BA%E5%8C%AF%E6%AC%BE_PDF.pdf)

there're two checkbox on the top-left of the form, one is for English UI, the other is Chinese, I just want to know how to make PDF like that sample? (and I don't see any layers on the sample...)

thx

Answer (score 1):

mkl's comment (which he should turn into a full answer, really) already hinted at the option to use different page templates residing in the same file.

Another option you could explore is this:

- put the two language versions into 2 different *layers* (or 'optional content groups' in PDF parlance)
- make the visibility of the two layers toggeable
- let the user activate that layer which he/she needs.

Layer activation can be handled through normal Acrobat Reader user interface elements.

The layer switching can be made accessible via a "button" on the PDF page too -- but that requires additional JavaScript to be embedded in the PDF (something many people are not particularly keen about).

Comment: This is a nice solution. The only drawback I can foresee is that it will be tricky to get forms containing default values in fields to switch the language on those default values. But again it should be feasible with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As Kurt proposed, I make my comment on Frank's answer an answer in its own right:

> Actually there is a pdf feature seldomly used nowerdays, page
>   templates. Thus, those two forms can reside in the same file in
>   different page templates, and based on some initially present buttons
>   ("English version", ...) the desired form is spawned.

Unfortunately I don't know how to create page templates using some easy-to-use tool, I only came a cross them in the context of integrated PDF signatures (depending on the signature type, page template instantiation is a document change not breaking the signature) and tested them with low-level tools.

Essentially page templates are PDF objects just like page dictionaries of the normal pages, they are not XFA stuff. They merely are not referenced in the pages tree but instead in the name tree.

There is a JavaScript command which creates a visible page based on such a template --- I don't know which anymore; I may be able to find out when I'm back in office next week. This command would have to be bound to the inital language selection button in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be in switching the static text - PDF does not allow this.

If I were you, I would split the document into two identical forms in the respective languages. You can use bookmarks and links on the first page to navigate to the right part of the document.

Note that it is possible to assign the same field names to the Enlgish/Chinese versions of your fields. This will make it easier to process the submitted form data because the process path would be independent of the chosen language. It will also simplify any JavaScript (validation, summing, etc.) you plan to add.

Comment: Actually there is a pdf feature seldomly used nowerdays, page templates. Thus, those two forms can reside in the same file in different page templates, and based on some initially present buttons ("English version", ...) the desired form is spawned.